# Java Iterator value sustaination

Tags: java, collections, iterator, set

I have a very basic java iterator scenario...in which am facing the below problem on finding the working of the iterator

Will the iterator logIterator have the same values in both the while loops,or it would have ended and become null in the second while loop.

```
Set logSet=transactionLogMap.entrySet();
Iterator logIterator=logSet.iterator();
BigDecimal tempRegId=null;

while (logIterator.hasNext()) {
    tempRegId=(BigDecimal)logIterator.next();
}

if (someBoolean) {
     while (logIterator.hasNext()) {
         callsomeMethod(logIterator.next());
     }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will get to the end before the second loop, but it will not become null.

It will just return `false` for `logIterator.hasNext()`

Answer (score 1):

Those will be different values. Your second loop returns `false`.

> [Iterators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics

Answer (score 0):

You are just reusing the old iterator. Once it returns `true` for `hasNext()`, he will keep doing so. You won't enter your second loop.

Apart from that, learn to use the new `for` construct

```
for(BigDecimal tempRegId : transactionLogMap.entrySet() {
}
```

Comment: for (Entry<BigDecimal, TransactionLogDTO> tempRegId : transactionLogMap.entrySet()) {